# How to fix 'Image not loading when loaded in mobile'?

Tags: html, css

The image which I use in the html(PC) loads properly, I have used img tag. I have saved and sent this file along with the image to my mobile, but it won't load there. I don't have any issues with the image size or anything. I think it has to do something with the image location.

I have tried keeping the html file and the image file in the same location but still hasn't worked. And should I use css for displaying the image instead of html?

```css
img {
  border: 10px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="sunflowers.jpg" alt="sunflowers">
```

I expect the image to be displayed properly when I view it on my mobile but it shows the text in the alt attribute

Comment: How are are testing in mobile through any live link?

Comment: Hi, is it the true code ? I think you have a error on src path where is hosted your image ?

Comment: Where is your image saved? A screenshot from your folder structure might help. If (for example) your html file is in the folder `My_Website` and your image is in a folder inside `My_Website` called `images` then you have to put the correct pathing like `<img src="images/sunflowers.jpg" alt="sunflowers">`

Comment: The image and the html file are in the same location. It loads in my pc but not on mobile. And I am opening the html file on mobile using chrome.

Comment: Okay Guys it worked! I opened it in firefox. Thank you everyone! I guess something is wrong with my chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "I have saved and sent this file along with the image to my mobile"? Is this being tested on a server or are you just trying to open an html file on your phone to view?

Comment: I copy/pasted this onto my phone. I am just trying to view the file through my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is probably not granting the html file access to other files. You will need to host your html file somewhere. There are a lot of hosting options, even for free, if you just google for simple html hosting. Also you could host the file on your private network. Checkout https://app.netlify.com/drop as an example.

Edit:
Also you could simply upload the picture online and use the webadress as source. Maybe give that a try first.